# iphone ABNewPersonViewController seems to not be responding to delegate

Tags: iphone, new-operator, addressbook, contacts

I'm halfway through implementing a very basic 'Add Contact' Button. I am calling the 'Add View' using the code (via a linked UIButton, that works) :

```
- (IBAction)showAddContact {
 NSLog(@"Hit showAddContact");

 ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];

 addContactNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonViewController];
 [self presentModalViewController:addContactNavController animated:YES];
}
```

and then I have also set the delegate resonse of:

```
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
  NSLog(@"Hit newPersonViewController");
 //ABContact *contact = [ABContact contactWithRecord:person]; 
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in my header I have set:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface test2ViewController : UIViewController <ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate> {
UINavigationController* addContactNavController;
}

- (IBAction)showAddContact;

@end
```

I have added the frameworks Addressbook and AddressBookUI.

The add dialog box comes up as expected, I can edit the contact, but I am not able to remove the modal View Controller from the view.

I have even duplicated the problem in a simple test project available here:[link text](http://norskben.posterous.com/stack-overflow-question-createnewcontact-dele)

What am I missing?, I bet it is something extremely simple.
Thanks @norskben

Comment: Just a minor grammar thing, but what you want to say is that your `ABNewPersonViewController` instance is not *calling* the delegate.

Comment: Looks like the final code I posted was a half-half combination of an attempt with a nav controller, and a modal view...must have been a long day yesterday. See my comment below for full solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems:

You should `release` the `ABNewPersonViewController` after presenting it.

You present the `ABNewPersonViewController` as a modal dialog with `presentModalViewController:` but you remove it from the screen as if it was pushed on a `UINavigationController` with `popViewControllerAnimated:`. Instead you should either *push* and *pop*, or *present* and *dismiss*. (If you don't know what this means, read a little int he View Controller documentation)

Even though you implement the `ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate` protocol, you never set the `delegate` property of the `ABNewPersonViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying .delegate = self, and it wasnt loading, but on using  newPersonViewController.newPersonViewDelegate = self;  it worked as expected! Cheers. To all future browsers with the same question heres an example for you: http://norskben.posterous.com/iphoneos-addressbook-create-new-client-and-ge